# How to add text before the output of function()

Tags: javascript

I would like to add some text before the onchange="input()" function.
anyone knows the trick? cheers

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function input(){
            var input_taker = document.getElementById('email').value;
            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = input_taker;
        }
    </script>


</head>

<form method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email@example.com" id="email"  onchange="input()">
<input type="submit" name="save" value="save">
```

Comment: so, `document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "some other text" + input_taker;` ?

Comment: Legend @JaromandaX, thanks so much!

Comment: @JaromandaX, For a smooth questions on stack overflow, please officially answer the question so that it can be accepted. This way people who sort by unanswered questions will know that this question is answered.

Comment: @programmerRaj - if you want to answer the question to get some point up, be my guest. Frankly, I can't believe my comment **was the answer**, and such questions/answers are barely useful to first day javascript noobs

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok I understand you were kind of asking for clarification and ended up answering the question.

Comment: @programmerRaj - exactly :p